How to convert a date in persian calender to georgian?
I want to convert a date from persian calender to Gregorian calendar in python (June,July ,....)
But i dont want to use any library .
I couldnt find the algorythm anywhere.
I read the the topics about this but they all used libraries.

If you don't want to use a library, you could look at how the persiontools library implements the conversion in source code.

I did create something in the past, I am not sure what python version you are using but here is the sample code.
This function uses the algorithm described in the "conversation between Persian and Gregorian calendar" Persian calendar
Here is the code
def persian_to_gregorian(day, month, year):
    """Convert Persian date to Gregorian date.

    Args:
        day (int): Persian day (1-31).
        month (int): Persian month (1-12).
        year (int): Persian year (1-9999).

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing the Gregorian date (year, month, day).
    """
    g_day, g_month, g_year = 0, 0, 0
    jy, jm, jd = year, month, day

    if jm < 7:
        jy -= 621
    else:
        jy -= 622

    gy = 474 + ((8 * jy + 1385) // 2500) + ((jy % 4) * 100 + 74) // 100 + jd + (((jm - 1) * 31 + 30 * (11 - jm)) // 30)
    gy += -1595 + ((33 * (gy + 1) // 100) + 3) // 4

    g_day = gy % 100
    g_month = (gy % 100 // 10) + 1
    g_year = gy // 100 + 1900

    if g_day < 31:
        if g_month < 13:
            return (g_year, g_month, g_day)
        else:
            return (g_year - 1, g_month - 12, g_day)
    else:
        return (g_year - 1, g_month - 1, g_day - 31)

# Example usage
day, month, year = 1, 1, 1395
print(persian_to_gregorian(day, month, year))

# Output: (2016, 3, 20)

This function takes the Persian day, month, and year as input and in return the Gregorian date as the tuple (year, month, day). I am not doing any validation it's assuming the data is valid.
